# How to type text or number on a cell which already have a formula in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

Hi I am expecting to use Excel for stock management. My problem is,to simply put, I need 3 cells; 'quantity' , 'rate per piece' and 'total'.
If I put values on quantity and rate I need result in total. At the same time if i put values on quantity and total I need result in rate per piece.
How to do that together on excel ?

Comment: You will need separate cells from the formula.  Manual inputs and formula cannot be in the same cell.  Or you will need vba in a worksheet_change event.

Comment: Add a 4th column and adjust the formula to take this column if non-empty, else compute.

Answer (score 0):

If you could know the type of entry in each of the cells, you could choose to wait for an entry to be made or to run a calculation.

Excel has a function for exactly that... oh... no, it doesn't. The `TYPE` function only tells you the Type of whatever the result in a cell is, whether straight data entry or a formula result. It doesn't tell you about the actual material entered in the cell, that there is a formula present, for example.

However, Excel finally introduced a function called `FORMULATEXT` which will return the formula that is in a cell, and, helpfully for your need, an error if no formula is present. So now you can test for the presence of a formula.

So, assuming your entry will occur in cells A2:C2 for Quantity, Rate, and Total, use the following formulas in this order:

```
=IFERROR(IFERROR(FORMULATEXT(C2),C2)/IFERROR(FORMULATEXT(B2),B2),"Entry?")

=IFERROR(IFERROR(FORMULATEXT(C2),C2)/IFERROR(FORMULATEXT(A2),A2),"Entry?")

=IFERROR(IFERROR(FORMULATEXT(A2),A2)*IFERROR(FORMULATEXT(B2),B2),"Entry?")
```

Take the last one. If A2 has a formula, that text is returned to the formula in C2. Same with B2. So if both have a formula (so no entry by the user), two strings are returned and multiplied by each other giving an error. The outer `IFERROR` then returns the string "Entry?" which can be anything you like, and not just a string of that sort.

If either of the cells contains a user entered value, that `FORMULATEXT` will return an error and the inner `IFERROR` that wraps it will give the formula the actual value in the cell. If only one of them has a value, you have a value times a string giving an error and therefore the "Entry?" string.

If both have no formula, then both return the value that is in each and the arithmetic for whichever one is performed. In the case of the last one, that is multiplication. For the other two, it is division.

So the end result is that no entries in any of the cells gives three cells displaying "Entry?". An entry in one cell, but not the others shows that entry (because it wiped out the formula...) and the "Entry?" string in the other two. Upon entering a value in one of the other two cells, the third immediately changes to the result its arithmetic is set for.

Bear in mind that none of this resets. So if a user enters a value for Quantity, then thinks "Oopsy, that goes in Rate." and deletes it, then enters it in the Rate cell for the row, it's all over as the Quantity has lost its formula and has a value of 0.

Excel cannot, on its own, have a formula in a cell that persists after a user enters a value overtop it. Using VBA, you can easily accomplish such a thing, in effect anyway, but then you could easily make a macro that opens a quick form for the user to fill two of the values and press Enter to load. It could activate on selecting the cell, then any keypress that would enter data.

And with the formula approach above, you could still have a macro written that would let a user click a button to restore the formulas to pristine shape and begin his data entry for the row all over. That would take care of the problem mentioned above, but does still require the macro.

However, assuming you have Users of Quality, not loser users (or "Lusers"), the above formulas can do the job for you. Especially if in a formal Table where the copying down a column of formulas as rows are added would very nicely put them in each new row, as needed.